React button refuses to activate function properly onClick
I am trying to set up a React component that includes two text input boxes and a button. When I click on the button, I would like for it to make a post request to the backend. However, either the text boxes activate the function, or the function refuses to activate.
Originally, typing in the boxes would activate the onClick event, and I could get onLogin({username, password}) to fire. In an attempt to get this to stop happening when I typed in the boxes and instead to happen when I clicked the button, I tried to make a click handler function, buttonClickHandler, in my Login() function. Now, clicking on the button doesn't activate the buttonClickHandler function nor the onLogin() function. While I am new to React and JavaScript and I understand that I may be using the wrong forms of functions (still heavily confused), I was wondering if there's a deeper structural issue with the way I have my functions set up. Thanks!
import React from 'react';
import './Login.css';
import Button from './button';
import {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

function TestToken({token}) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/login/test_token', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Token ' + token
        }
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        return(true);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error + ", token authentication failed!");
        return(false);
    });
};

function OnLogin({username, password}) {
    alert("BUTTON CLICKED RAHHHH");
    const [token, setToken] = useState("");

    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login',
        {
            username: {username},
            password: {password}
        }
    ).then(response => {
        setToken(response.data.token)
        console.log(response.data.user)
    }).catch(error => {console.log(error)});

    if(TestToken(token)) {
        console.log("Logged in!");
    } else {
        console.log("Log in failed!");
    };

    return(console.log("OnLogin function concluded!"));

};


export function Login() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    function getUser(event) {
        setUsername(event.target.value);
    }

    function getPassword(event) {
        setPassword(event.target.value);
    }

    const buttonClickHandler = () => {
        console.log("Handle activated");
        OnLogin({username, password});
    }
        return(
            <div className= "functional-box">
            <div className= "login-page">
            <div className= "login-title">Log In</div>
            <div className= "inputs">
                <input className= "input-text" onChange={getUser} type="text" placeholder='Username'/>
                <input className= "input-text" onChange={getPassword} type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>
            <div className="button-div"><Button className="login-button" text="Login" onClick={buttonClickHandler}></Button></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
}


export default Login;

The Login() function is called in my App class and seems to be working fine there because the HTML is showing up.
import './App.css';
import Card from './components/Card.jsx'
import Login from './components/Login.jsx'
import { LoggedInSidebar, LoggedOutSidebar } from './components/Sidebar.jsx';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Button from './components/button.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-page">

        <div className="topbar">
          <div className="topbar-title">Glass Table</div>
        </div>

        <div className= "main-box-div">

          <div className="login-sidebar">
            <LoggedOutSidebar></LoggedOutSidebar>
          </div>

          <div className="functional-box">
            <Login></Login>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default App;

And finally the button class which was borrowed from a template website. I don't believe that it adjusts the onClick function?
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Button = ({text}) => {
  return (
    <StyledWrapper>
      <button className="animated-button">
        <svg
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          className="arr-2"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path d="M16.1716 10.9999L10.8076 5.63589L12.2218 4.22168L20 11.9999L12.2218 19.778L10.8076 18.3638L16.1716 12.9999H4V10.9999H16.1716Z" />
        </svg>
        <span className="text">{text}</span>
        <span className="circle" />
        <svg
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          className="arr-1"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path d="M16.1716 10.9999L10.8076 5.63589L12.2218 4.22168L20 11.9999L12.2218 19.778L10.8076 18.3638L16.1716 12.9999H4V10.9999H16.1716Z" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </StyledWrapper>
  );
};

const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
  .animated-button {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
  padding: 16px 36px;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: greenyellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px greenyellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.animated-button svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  fill: greenyellow;
  z-index: 9;
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.animated-button .arr-1 {
  right: 16px;
}

.animated-button .arr-2 {
  left: -25%;
}

.animated-button .circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.animated-button .text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(-12px);
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.animated-button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px transparent;
  color: #212121;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.animated-button:hover .arr-1 {
  right: -25%;
}

.animated-button:hover .arr-2 {
  left: 16px;
}

.animated-button:hover .text {
  transform: translateX(12px);
}

.animated-button:hover svg {
  fill: #212121;
}

.animated-button:active {
  scale: 0.95;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px greenyellow;
}

.animated-button:hover .circle {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  opacity: 1;
}

`;

export default Button;



The reason why the onClick event listener isn't firing on the button is because the Button component's props are not copied alongside the text prop. You need to copy props to your component to be able to call the onClick function when you render the Button component. You should refactor your Button component as follows:
const Button = (props) => {
const { text } = props
  return (
    <StyledWrapper>
      <button className="animated-button" {...props}>
        <svg
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          className="arr-2"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path d="M16.1716 10.9999L10.8076 5.63589L12.2218 4.22168L20 11.9999L12.2218 19.778L10.8076 18.3638L16.1716 12.9999H4V10.9999H16.1716Z" />
        </svg>
        <span className="text">{text}</span>
        <span className="circle" />
        <svg
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          className="arr-1"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path d="M16.1716 10.9999L10.8076 5.63589L12.2218 4.22168L20 11.9999L12.2218 19.778L10.8076 18.3638L16.1716 12.9999H4V10.9999H16.1716Z" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </StyledWrapper>
  );
};

Your buttonClickHandler() function should get triggered now.
